# How to build openCV 3.3.0 with GStreamer on Windows

Tags: opencv, cmake, gstreamer

Having Gstreamer 1.22 successfully installed I'm not able to configure the project to build OpenCV. CMake isn't able to find GStreamer on my machine. Any ideas how two address this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Just found the solution:
Cmake is using `FindGstreamerWindows.cmake` to find GStreamer on Windows, which is using internal an environment variable called "`GSTREAMER_DIR`" pointing to `..\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64.`

Please make sure `GSTREAMER_DIR` exists on your machine.

Comment: Hi sir! I also have the same problem, I have already added the same thing as you mentioned in the answer, but the problem still exists, could you tell me that which version of GStreamer you downloaded, I saw there were three groups, for x86, x64 and dev, I download the x64, which my machine is 64bit. Thanks!

Comment: The problem now is, I can successfully open the IP camera, but when I want to pushout to a media server like NGINX it not working.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not am expert with NGINX and this question is not realeated to this topic. You should ask a new one. Good luck

Comment: OK, I know it does not belong to NGINX, but I want to ask how to use GStreamer to send/push frames to a media server like to NGINX media servers.

Comment: hi. at last what version do you use.i download the x64 version,and found still some file is missing, for example  glib.h, should i use the dev version of gstreamer?

Comment: @GregPhil Hi did you able to run Opencv with Gstreamer on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I recently compile Opencv 4.2 with GStreamer on Windows. I use settings for GStreamer as on the following pictures. Make sure you point to correct .lib and include directories. all_Library is gstapp-1.0.lib etc, when configuraing CMAKE to compile OpenCV.

I use Opencv 4.2, CMake 3.17.0 release candidate and Gstreamer 1.16.2 MSVC 64-bit (VS 2019) developer and runtime installer. The whole process is described here [install OpenCV on windows GStreamer tutorial](https://funvision.blogspot.com/2020/03/compile-opencv-4-for-visual-studio-2019.html) 
 [image: Cmake setting]

The important part is to set up environmental variables to find Gstreamer Runtime. Into system variable path: add

- xxx\1.0\x86_64\bin
- xxx\1.0\x86_64\lib
- xxx\1.0\x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0

[image]

Gstreamer pipe from c++ opencv program to the web. 
[image]